# How to fix mat-paginator size

Tags: css, angular

In `mat-table` for pagination, there is no flexibility for `sticky-table`.
In pagination after move there is no `css` is apply (as shown in images).
I tried to give a background color but it is not working. refer this code :
https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbmgqanjelq?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.css

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
.mat-paginator{
    background-color: brown;
    color: gold;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.mat-header-cell{
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: brown;
    color: gold;
  }
.example-container {
  height: 460px;
  width: 550px;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

<!-- Star Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="star" stickyEnd>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 </table>

<mat-paginator [length]="50" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]" showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>
</div>
```

if we move the table paginator should look same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything at this point.

The sticky is very tricky to use, that's why you should avoid using it (also it's [not that well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)).

You could add `background: brown;` to your `.example-container`, which would result in this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxdsdk?file=app/table-sticky-columns-example.css

[image]

Maybe you could explain your end-goal, and we could come up with an alternative ?

Answer (score 6):

Okay I'm adding another answer because this one is totally different from the previous one.

You can use the Angular renderer along with view children to incread the size of the paginator to the size of the table.

Here is the stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxdsdk-d2b7xa?file=app/table-sticky-columns-example.ts

As you can see, the paginator gets the total size of the table and is displayed on the right. Not sure you want it, but it gives you a new way of using it.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #table>
 ...
 <mat-paginator sticky #paginator></mat-paginator>
```

```js
@ViewChild('table', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) table: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
@ViewChild('paginator', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) paginator: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

constructor(
  private renderer: Renderer2
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const width = this.table.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.paginator.nativeElement, 'width', width + 'px');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue, but got fixed.

Place the mat-paginator outside the container div of , then this pagination width issue won't even arise at first. The scroll will apply only on table data itself, not on pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `::ng-deep` property in your `scss` or `css` like this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator{
    background-color: brown;
    color: gold;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

::ng-deep .mat-header-cell{
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: brown;
    color: gold;
}
```

For more information about ng-deep, check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

Comment: The question doesn't offer enough context for you or me to provide an answer suited for the issue : consider asking for more information before providing an answer !

Comment: @Maryannah I don't agree with you. He tag the question as angular, and is clear by analyzing the css and the `mat-table` that is using the angular materials (from here) `https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api`. He can provide more details about the context, but you can understand the problem. The problem is that the css is not being applied to the materials components and for these case, most of the times the problems is because the `::ng-deep` property is not being used.

Comment: as shown in image in table paginator is not covering all table width when I go to the end of the row in sticky-table.

Comment: @Maryannah you really should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276971/upvoting-and-downvoting-reputation. "This is a feature introduced to the Stack Exchange communities so that downvoting is discouraged".